# Add 4D tensor of shape (16, 8, 8, 5) and 2D tensor of shape (16, 16)

Tags: python, tensor, torch

I want to add a noise of shape (16,16) to a 4D tensor of shape (16,8,8,5).
I have tried several broadcasting approaches but still get errors but I get singleton mismatch errors. How can I add these two tensors without any broadcasting errors.

Comment: you are asking how to add apples to oranges. Could you describe the dimensions of your 4D tensor (Batch, Width, Height, Channel??) and explain where you exactly want the noise added? For example the noise shall be added to width and height for each sample in the minibatch. The latter might be what you want, but this is only guessing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have dimensions like this (batch size, width, height, channels) or similar.

There is not enough noise for each element in the tensor, so some elements will have to share noise. I guess that the channel dimension will have to share their noises. Lets say the channels were RGB (colors). Then there will be a unique noise for every image, at every location, but just one for each color channel.

However, your noise does not fit to this (nor any other way).

If I described your case correctly, simply use noise of the correct shape (16,8,8)

If you had that kind of noise, it will work:

```
import torch

tensor1 = torch.ones((16,8,8,5))
tensor2 = torch.ones((16,8,8))

# you will need to reshape noise from 16x16 to 16x8x8
result = tensor1 * tensor2.reshape(16,8,8,1)   # add a last dimension for the channels
```

If I wasn't correct with my guessing, please elaborate

Comment: No, the noise cannot be reshaped as (16, 8, 8) since multiplying the 3 will result in 1024 which is larger than 16*16 =256. The 4D tensor represents molecule bond logits where 16 is batch size, 8x8 is the 8 bond connection between the atoms of the molecule, 5 is the atoms. The noise is randomly generated with dimension (16, 16)

Comment: and in an ideal world, which dimension should share the noise?

currently, it simply doesnt fit together, If you cannot adjust the noises' shape (why tell the random generator to provide more?). So you can either use less of it (e.g. one noise per sample from batch) or duplicate it.